# Having issues with generating 1 to 300 numbers between 1 to 100 and placing each number in a String

Tags: java, loops, if-statement, random, output

I'm trying to accept a number in the range 1 to 300 from the user, then generate the amount of random numbers that was inputted. Then if the numbers generated are in the range 1 to 10, I add an asterisk to a String, then I do the same for 11 to 20 etc. all the way up to 100. Although I keep getting errors saying "; expected" in the results portion of my code. The output I'm trying to achieve is:

1 to 10 ****************

11 to 20 ******

21 to 30 ***************

31 to 40 ********************

41 to 50

51 to 60  ***********

61 to 70 ****************

71 to 80 ****

81 to 90 *******

91 to 100 **

The asterisks above may not add up to 100, but I'm trying to get 100 asterisks displayed in the output, each one representing a random generated number in the range __ to __.

The code I have is below.

```
import java.util.*;
public class histogramAsterisks
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Please enter a number between the range 1 to 300: ");
        int input = Integer.parseInt(in.nextLine());
        int aNumber;
        String 1to10 = "", 11to20 = "", 21to30= "", 31to40 = "", 41to50 = ""; 51to50 = ""; 61to70 = ""; 71to80 = ""; 81to90 = ""; 91to100 = "", results = "";
        if(input < 1 || input > 300 || input == null)
            results = "Please enter a valid input in the range 1 to 300.";
        else
        {
            for(int i = 0; i < input; i++)
            {
                aNumber = (int) (Math.random() * 100 + 1);
                if(aNumber <= 10)               1to10   += "*";
                else if(aNumber <= 20)          11to20  += "*";
                else if(aNumber <= 30)          21to30  += "*";
                else if(aNumber <= 40)          31to40  += "*";
                else if(aNumber <= 50)          41to50  += "*";
                else if(aNumber <= 60)          51to60  += "*";
                else if(aNumber <= 70)          61to70  += "*";
                else if(aNumber <= 80)          71to80  += "*";
                else if(aNumber <= 90)          81to90  += "*";
                else                            91to100 += "*";
            }
        }
        results  = "1 to 10\t\t\t" + 1to10;
        results += "\n11 to 20\t\t\t" + 11to20;
        results += "\n21 to 30\t\t\t" + 21to30;
        results += "\n31 to 40\t\t\t" + 31to40;
        results += "\n41 to 50\t\t\t" + 41to50;
        results += "\n51 to 60\t\t\t" + 51to60;
        results += "\n61 to 70\t\t\t" + 61to70;
        results += "\n71 to 80\t\t\t" + 71to80;
        results += "\n81 to 90\t\t\t" + 81to90;
        results += "\n91 to 100\t\t\t" + 91to100;
        System.out.println(results);
    }
}
```

Comment: if your range was from 1 to 100000 instead of 1 to 100, would you use 1to10, 11to20, ..., 99991 to 100000? Think of how you can use arrays in this question, this way you wont need to bother with `if else`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code for String declaration you have used semi colon (;) instead of coma (,) for separation of variable declaration. Change as below line. And also please change variable names.

String 1to10 = "", 11to20 = "", 21to30= "", 31to40 = "", 41to50 = "", 51to50 = "", 61to70 = "", 71to80 = "",81to90 = "", 91to100 = "", results = "";

Answer (score 1):

As described at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/variables.html a variable name must:

> A variable's name can be any legal identifier — an unlimited-length sequence of Unicode letters and digits, beginning with a letter, the dollar sign "$", or the underscore character "_".

You are trying to create a bunch of variables starting with numbers, for instance `1to10`, which are not valid.

---

You could probably solve this easier by using arrays instead. So, create an array with the "buckets" of results you are expecting, and place the result in that instead. I have edited your code and inserted it below to demonstrate. At the moment you get a number instead of asterisks, but you can easily change that once you understand the code.

```
import java.util.*;
public class histogramAsterisks
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Please enter a number between the range 1 to 300: ");
        int input = Integer.parseInt(in.nextLine());
        double aNumber;
        int[] results = new int[10];
        for ( int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) { results[i] = 0; }
        if (input < 1 || input > 300)
        {
            System.out.println("Please enter a valid input in the range 1 to 300.");
            return;
        }
        for(int i = 0; i < input; i++)
        {
           aNumber = (Math.random() * 100 + 1);
           int bucket = (int)(aNumber / 10);
           ++results[bucket];
        }

        for (int i = 0 ; i < 10; ++i)
        {
            System.out.println(i + "1 to " + i + "0\t\t\t" + results[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

With an input of 10, this prints:

> ```
> Please enter a number between the range 1 to 300: 10
> 01 to 00          2
> 11 to 10          0
> 21 to 20          1
> 31 to 30          2
> 41 to 40          2
> 51 to 50          0
> 61 to 60          2
> 71 to 70          0
> 81 to 80          0
> 91 to 90          1
> ```

Comment: It'd be a good idea to use `StringBuilder` instead of `String`, too.

Answer (score 1):

The "; expected" is caused by the line where you declare the "XtoY" strings:

```
String 1to10 = "", 11to20 = "", 21to30= "", 31to40 = "", 41to50 = ""; 51to50 = ""; 61to70 = ""; 71to80 = ""; 81to90 = ""; 91to100 = "", results = "";
```

Two problems ocurr:

- As stated in other answers, a variable's name may not begin with a digit(0-9). You can begin the name with an underscore, though discouraged, or change it to something else.
- Always use a comma to separate multiple variables declarations. In the line above, some of the variables have been separated by a semi-colon(;)

Your program has a lot of room to improvement. I sugest you also take a look in the following links:

[`Scanner.nextInt()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextInt%28%29) - Method for reading integers from a stream.

[`StringBuilder`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) - A class better suited for multiple string concatenations.

Hope it helps ;)