# Creating a histogram of asterisks with randomly generated numbers

Tags: random, histogram

So basically i have to use the random generator to generate 100 random number between 1 and 10 and then have them add up for a sum, and then have a histogram that displays asterisks for each number that came up... I think I got the first part right but I tried using this guide below for the second part but im really not too sure how to apply it to my numbers... Any help would be great

Hey guys I looked around and found something similar here: [Having issues with generating 1 to 300 numbers between 1 to 100 and placing each number in a String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26908311/having-issues-with-generating-1-to-300-numbers-between-1-to-100-and-placing-each)

```
/**
 * Write a description of class RandomCalculator here.
 * 
 * @author (your name) 
 * @version (a version number or a date)
 */
import java.util.Random;
public class RandomCalculator
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Random r = new Random();
        System.out.println(" The one hundred random values are: ");
        int[] values = new int[100];
        for(int i =0; i<10; i++)
        {
            int randomint = r.nextInt(100);
            values[i] = randomint;
            System.out.print(" , " + randomint);
        }
        int sum = 0;
        for(int i : values) {
            sum+= i;
        }
        System.out.println("Sum =  " + sum);
    }
    int input = Integer.parseInt(in.nextLine());
        int aNumber;
        String One = "", Two = "", Three= "", Four = "", Five = "", Six = "", Seven = "", Eight = "", Nine = "", Ten = "", ;
      if (randomint<1 || randomint >100)

        else
        {
            for(int i = 0; i < input; i++)
            {
                aNumber = (int) (Math.random() * 100 + 1);
                if(aNumber <= 1)               One   += "*";
                else if(aNumber <= 2)            Two += "*";
                else if(aNumber <= 3)          Three  += "*";
                else if(aNumber <= 4)          Four  += "*";
                else if(aNumber <= 5)          Five  += "*";
                else if(aNumber <= 6)          Six  += "*";
                else if(aNumber <= 7)          Seven  += "*";
                else if(aNumber <= 8)          Eight  += "*";
                else if(aNumber <= 9)
        else if(aNumber <= 10)            Nine += "*";
                else                            Ten += "*";
            }
        }

    }
}
    }
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Im gettting an <identfier> expected at the String One = line and I have no idea what to do with it

Comment: You have an extra comma at the end of that line...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to generate 100 random numbers between 1 and 10, but your code generates 10 random numbers between 0 (inclusive) and 99 (inclusive).

You have to change your first for loop to loop 100 times instead of 10 and change the line

`int randomint = r.nextInt(100);`

to

`int randomint = 1 + r.nextInt(10);`

This will guarantee a number on interval [1,10] (both inclusive).

For the histogram part you want to create another array that will store histogram bins (frequencies for each histogram bar/column). You can update histogram bins and also update the sum in the first loop, there is no need for the second loop.

Then use a second loop (double for loop) to print out the histogram bins (outer loop for lines, inner loop for asterisks).

Example: https://ideone.com/xjBK6i

Comment: @AustinSilliker: If this solves your problem, remember to accept the answer. Otherwise leave a comment on what's still missing.